# how to pass data from ajax to the form url in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

here i have fetched the data through ajax and i have successfully passed the data to the bootstrap modal but there is a problem that howto pass the id value to the form url

```
$.ajax({
            url: '{{URL::to('edit')}}',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'id': $id},
            success:function(data){

              var data = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
              console.log(data);
              for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                  $('.modal-body #name').val(data[i].name);
                  $('.modal-body #email').val(data[i].email);
                  $('.modal-body #phone').val(data[i].phone);
                  $('.modal-body #status').val(data[i].status);
                  $('#meroModal').modal('show');
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
url: '{{URL::to('edit')}}',
```

to

```
url: '{{ url('edit') }}',
```

and try again.